# need a simple linq

Tags: linq

I have a table called products. I want to get all products that have productID 2 OR 6 OR 9
the SQL is : `Select * from products where productID=2 OR productID=6 OR ProductID=9`.
How can I do this sql by LINQ? The productIds are in an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from p in Products
where new int [] { 2,6,9 }.Contains(p.ProductID)
select p;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var q = from p in Products
        where p.productID==2 || p.productID==6 || p.productID==9
        select p;

foreach(var product in q)
{
  //...
}
```

or simply:

```
db.Products.Where(p=> p.productID==2 || p.productID==6 || p.productID==9)
```

Comment: How can I do your solution by foreach? The productIds are in an array.

Comment: I added the foreach statement